# aAddon._repositoryAddon is null when installing Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, kango-framework

I've created an extension using kango-framework, it works ok in Chrome and Opera 20, but when installing it on Firefox 27 or 28, I get error "aAddon._repositoryAddon is null".
Any guess? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think aAddon has _repositoryAddon as a parameter. Find out by including Console.jsm and then going `console.log('aAddon',aAddon)`. (Try just doing console.log Console.jsm might already be included). Then open up Browser Console. then in browser console, should be latest entry, find your aAddon msg then on the link next to it, click it, and it opens in variable viewer. There you can see what all properties aAddon has.
http://smg.photobucket.com/user/noitidart/media/i20dont20see20nsIInterfaceRequestor_zps7bfc9d43.png.html?sort=3&o=12

http://smg.photobucket.com/user/noitidart/media/my20code20works_zpsdd244f45.png.html?sort=3&o=11